# Pin Collection View Header at bottom of Collection View except expended header

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have multiple header section in collection view. I want to pin one header section at top(which is already a feature of uicollection view) and second header section at bottom of uicollectionview and rest are below. I mean i want to scroll only data under the header section. Please reply if any suggestion for any other way to do this[image: view controller with visible and invisible Rect]

i used this to stick header at top:

```
if let layout = groupCollectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
        layout.sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds = true
    }
```

My Code is:

```
extension GrpLVController: UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
{
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
{
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width/3, height: 200)
}

func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int
{
    return totalSec.count
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize
{
    return CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 36)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView
{
    switch kind {
    case UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader:
        let  headerV: GCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "GCell", for: indexPath) as! GCell
        
        headerV.headerBackGroundView.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
        headerV.headerBackGroundView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        
        let plusBtn = headerV.viewWithTag(101) as? UIButton
        if self.totalSec[indexPath.section] == selectedIndx
        {
            plusBtn?.setImage(UIImage(named: "Close"), for: .normal)
        }
        else
        {
            plusBtn?.setImage(UIImage(named: "Open"), for: .normal)
        }
        
        headerV.hDelegate = self
        
        headerV.headerBtnOut.tag = indexPath.section
        
        let sectionn = self.totalSec[indexPath.section]
        
        let lbl = headerV.viewWithTag(100) as? UILabel
        if sectionn == .Grp_Sugestion
        {
            lbl?.text = "Group suggestions"
        }
        else if sectionn == .MyGrp
        {
            lbl?.text = "My groups  (\(myGList.count))"
        }
        else if sectionn == .InvitesReceivedCorrect
        {
            lbl?.text = "Invites Received  (\(inviteList.count))"
        }
        else
        {
            lbl?.text = "Requests Sent  (\(requestedList.count))"
        }
        return headerV
    default:
        return UICollectionReusableView()
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    let sectionn = self.totalSec[section]
    if sectionn == .Grp_Suggestion && selectedIndx == .Grp_Suggestion
    {
        if suggestedList.count % 3 == 0
        {
            return suggestedList.count
        }
        else
        {
            return suggestedList.count - (suggestedList.count % 3) + 3
        }
    }
    else if sectionn == .MyGrp && selectedIndx == .MyGrp
    {
        if myGList.count % 3 == 0
        {
            return myGList.count
        }
        else
        {
            return myGList.count - (myGList.count % 3) + 3
        }
    }
    else if sectionn == .InvitesCorrect && selectedIndx == .InvitesCorrect
    {
        if inviteReveivedList.count % 3 == 0
        {
            return inviteList.count
        }
        else
        {
            return inviteList.count - (inviteList.count % 3) + 3
        }
    }
    else if sectionn == .InvitesReceived && selectedIndx == .InvitesReceived
    {
        if requestedList.count % 3 == 0
        {
            return requestedList.count
        }
        else
        {
            return requestedList.count - (requestedList.count % 3) + 3
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return 0
    }
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "GroupGridCell", for: indexPath) as! GroupGridCell
    cell.headerDelegate = self
    
    let sectionn = self.totalSec[indexPath.section]
    
    if sectionn == .Grp_Suggestion
    {
        if suggestedList.count > indexPath.row
        {
            cell.conf_G_InfoCell(group: suggestedList[indexPath.row])
        }
        else
        {
            cell.contentSubView.isHidden = true
        }
    }
    else if sectionn == .MyGroup
    {
        if myGList.count > indexPath.row
        {
            cell.configureGroupCell(group: myGList[indexPath.row])
        }
        else
        {
            cell.contentSubView.isHidden = true
        }
    }
    else if sectionn == .InvitesRCorrect
    {
        if inviteList.count > indexPath.row
        {
            cell.configureInviteCell(invite: inviteList[indexPath.row])
        }
        else
        {
            cell.contentSubView.isHidden = true
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if requestedList.count > indexPath.row
        {
            cell.configureInviteCell(invite: requestedList[indexPath.row])
        }
        else
        {
            cell.contentSubView.isHidden = true
        }
    }
    
    cell.contentSubView.layer.cornerRadius = 7.0
    cell.contentSubView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    cell.contentSubView.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
    cell.contentSubView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor

    cell.RJoinBtn.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    cell.RJoinBtn.layer.borderColor = UIColor.systemGreen.cgColor
    cell.RJoinBtn.layer.cornerRadius = 12.0
    cell.RJoinBtn.layer.masksToBounds = true

    cell.ivGPic.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    cell.ivGPic.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    cell.ivGPic.layer.cornerRadius =  8
    cell.ivGPic.layer.masksToBounds = true
    
    return cell
}
```

}